# Can I ask a friend who works as a therapist for recommendation letter for grad degree to become a therapist?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, recommendation-letter

I am applying for a Masters in Clinical Mental Health Counseling to become a therapist. I'm looking for a third recommendation for my application, and I have a friend who works as a therapist. We did church service together for 6 months and worked closely with her. I know it's generally not a great idea to ask a friend for a recommendation, but since we've worked together in some capacity and she's working in my chosen field, I wondered if she would be a good recommender. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Look at it from the point of view of the recipient of the letter.

(1) What can the letter writer say about your aptitude for the studies and the benefits of giving you this education?

Your friend seems to be OK, but not great on this. You worked in a therapy related situation together.

(2) Is the person trustworthy?

This gives points to educators and employers, who are assumed to be trustworthy, but your friend looses out a bit. Your friend would need to explain the relationship well. Since your friend is a therapist, (s)he is expected to be honest, but assumed to be biased.

If you have already two other letters from more traditional sources, you should be fine. After all, no letter writer can guarantee that you do well in your studies and in your professional work afterwards.